# How to select ALL results from a SQL query and eliminate the null values

Tags: sql, subquery

Imagine I have four tables:

**Agents**

```
| agent_id | agent_name |
```

**Teams**

```
| team_id | team_name |agent_id |
```

**Menu**

```
| menu_id | menu_name |
```

**Team_assignment**

```
| menu_id | team_id|
```

I need to write a query that selects all agents that are assigned to all teams and all queues and disregard the ones that are not assigned to a queue. Note that every agent is always assigned to a team but it's not necessary that the agent is assigned to a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that this is for a school project, I'll try to stay within the guidelines mentioned here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

From what I can make up from your question you basically want to `select` all the data `from` the different `table`s `join`ing them `on` one of the columns in the first table `a` equals `=` a column from the second table `b`. Most commonly where the `primary key` from one table equals the `foreign key` from another table. Then you want to add conditions to your query `where` for example some column from table 1 equals `=` some value.

*Do you catch my drift?* 

*No?*

You want to [`SELECT a.*, b.*`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) everything `FROM` table `Agents a` [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)ing table `Teams b` `ON` column `a.agent_id` being equal to `=` column `b.agent_id`

You probably want to [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) another table, lets say `Team_assignment c` `ON` column `c.team_id` being equal to `=` `b.team_id`.

You can [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) more tables in the same way.

Sadly, I do not understand what you mean by `the ones that are not assigned to a queue` but it sounds like a condition that your query needs to match, so [`WHERE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) the potential column `a.is_assigned_to_queue` equals `=` `true` [`AND`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) for example `a.agent_name` [`IS NOT NULL`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

If you got this far you should have been able to catch onto my drift , congrats. This way hopefully you also got a better understanding of how building query works, instead of me just blatantly giving you the answer and you learn **nothing** from it. Like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.* FROM Agents a
JOIN Teams b ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id
JOIN Team_assignment c ON c.team_id = b.team_id
JOIN Menu d ON d.menu_id = c.menu_id
WHERE a.is_assigned_to_queue = true
  AND a.agent_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Now it is possible copy and pasting the snippet above will not work, that is because I'm not an SQL expert and I had to refresh my old memories about SQL myself by googling it. But that's the nice part of actually learning it. Being able to explain it to someone else :)